# Find Kafka records that were discarded on partition rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a service that listens to a Kafka topic and processes those events by persisting them in a datastore (the store actually maintains counts and other aggregates). I do not wish to reprocess the same message twice, otherwise, it would corrupt the data in the store. In other words message processing needs to be idempotent. We do have some solution in place for that, but that is a bit costly from a performance standpoint.

When we scale up the service, the partition is often rebalanced and we end up with discarded messages. Now, these messages may already have been processed and the counts incremented in the datastore before the rebalance got triggered.

Is there a way to find if the message from Kafka has been discarded due to rebalancing or other reasons? Is there any metadata in the ConsumerRecord that can help with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "_message from Kafka has been discarded due to rebalancing..._"?

Comment: Kafka doesn't provide 'exactly once delivery'  (if we do not speak about kafka - kafka flow). So, the only way - to have idempotent process on the end.

Comment: @Natalia - I am not concerned about the idempotence at producer level; but rather on the consumer side where we want to do exactly once processing of a message. So, any rebalancing should be taken care of as well.

Comment: @mazaneicha - I have updated the question

Comment: @praveenj Unfortunately, it didn't help. Consumer rebalancing by itself does not discard any messages from Kafka log.